# How to count number of code lines created by every user in github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm Working with some Collaborators on a project on Github, and we want to find out how much work did everyone does, as the percentage of code created or counting every line created to find out who did what ? is there any way to do it?

Comment: Just a disclaimer : this will count *something*, granted, but certainly not "how much work did everyone does" on the project. These type of metrics are always flawed and cheatable.

Comment: I agree with @RomainValeri, maybe good for a school project but this is not an accurate method or a metric. Days of researching would be implemented in 10 lines (solid, efficient and error free) of code, and 100 lines of codes could be written in 1 hour (junk code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your project, go to the `Insights` tab and then click on `Contributors`.

Here is an example on the `npm` project: https://github.com/npm/npm/graphs/contributors

You can see the number of commits, additions and deletions over any period of time you want.

Comment: what if a user isn't listed as a contributor?

Comment: Yeah, great. Now let me programmatically add a few thousands commits to the repo, then take a nap for two years while you guys try to keep up with my formidable "work".

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command in your repository :

```
git log --format='%aN' | Sort-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_
    $addedLines = 0
    $removedLines = 0
    (git log --author="$name" --pretty=tformat: --numstat) | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '(\d+)\s+(\d+)') {
            $addedLines += [int]$matches[1]
            $removedLines += [int]$matches[2]
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Author = $name
        AddedLines = $addedLines
        RemovedLines = $removedLines
        TotalLines = $addedLines - $removedLines
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```